# Application never exits sending data to child threads from main thread

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement SPMC using channels. So far I managed to get my child threads to receive the values but the application never exits, it just stands there:

```
    let (tx_n1, rx_n1) = channel::unbounded();
    let (tx_n2, rx_n2) = channel::unbounded();

    let handle_challenge_n1 = thread::spawn(move|| {
        for msg in &rx_n1 {
            println!("thread n1: Received {}", msg);
        }
        drop(rx_n1);
    });
    let handle_challenge_n2 = thread::spawn(move|| {
        for msg in &rx_n2 {
            println!("thread n2: Received {}", msg);
        }
        drop(rx_n2);
    });

    for i in 1..10 {
        tx_n1.send(i).unwrap();
        tx_n2.send(i).unwrap();
    }

    handle_challenge_n1.join().unwrap();
    handle_challenge_n2.join().unwrap();
    drop(tx_n1);
    drop(tx_n2);
    println!("Main thread: Exiting.")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receivers will wait for messages as long as senders exists. Only after you drop senders, loops in other threads will end and your threads could be joined. So change order of dropping senders with joining threads and it should work.